# wx.CallAfter to init frame

Tags: wxpython

We know that wxCallAfter works from function to function:

```
def onButton(self, event):
     wx.CallAfter(self.functionOne)

def functionOne(self):
     print "functionOne fired!"
```

How do you call an action using wx.CallAfter to the *init* using my objects?
I have an button pressed that in turn, changes a list at that *init* class.

Here is what I have progressed to:

```
class LeftPanel(wx.Panel):

def __init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent)       
    self.radioLabel = self.myListener(self,parent,*args, **kwargs)
    print 'Line 28 is %s' % self.radioLabel  ## Line 28 is None, looking for a list!
```

Below on same panel:

```
def myListener(self, message, arg2=None):
    print '378 left listener try is %s' % message
    self.radioLabel = message        
    try:
        wx.CallAfter(self.__init__)
    except TypeError:
        return
```

Traceback:

```
lambda event: event.callable(*event.args, **event.kw) )
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call a class, you instantiate it. So if you need to instantiate a class, I would do that in a method:

```
def someMethod(self):
    obj = SomeClass(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can call the method with wx.CallAfter:

```
wx.CallAfter(someMethod)
```

Comment: My class: class LeftPanel(wx.Panel):     
My Method: def __init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs): So wx.CallAfter the entire init?

Comment: No. In my example, I instantiate the class from within a method. I assume the method is in class A and is instantiating Class B. You may need to give more sample code or explain in more detail about what you want.

Comment: It's all in the same class. I never used CallAfter to the _init_ where the radio button (sizer) object appears when a file is open with it's list.

Comment: Then I don't think it will work. The init is only supposed to be called once. You don't call it again from within the class.

Comment: Yeah, thats a bad ideal. I worked around this by adding another panel. That way I'll use the CallAfter to that panel class.